# Selenium requesting wrong address when running on build server

Tags: selenium

I have a UI Test project that will run locally fine but when I run it on my build server it is failing with this error.

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:33868/session timed out after 60 seconds.

The first thing it is attempting to do is a simple navigate.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/MyTestSite");
```

As such I find it odd that the error message is showing a different URL.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

### Addendum

I am using the ChromeDriver

I deleted the chromedriver.exe from the build server and it started complaining that the driver did not exist, so I am assuming that it is at least finding the driver.

Comment: Which webDriver you use ?

Comment: try to use exact domain name

Comment: @LeonBarkan I am using the ChromeDriver

Comment: Try to look if you get  the web drivers phisicly on the server

Comment: The `chromedriver.exe` is in the bin, so i tried copying it to the root of the project which is where nuget put it in my solution but this did not help.